# Sum of last N nodes of a linked list

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

The problem given is that we have to find the sum of the last n nodes of a linked list.
Example if the list is this:-

```
1->2->3->4->5->6->7
```

and n is `3`

then answer should be 18 (from 5 + 6 + 7).

Here is my solution ->

```
Node*temp = head ; int sum = 0;int cnt = 1;
  if(n<=0){
      return 0 ;
  }
  while(cnt!=n)
  {
    temp = temp->next ;cnt+=1 ; 
  }
  temp = temp->next ;
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {
      sum+= temp->data ; temp = temp->next ;
  }

  return sum ;
```

The editor is giving a Segmentation Dump for some input cases. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: hi if you problem has been solve considering accepting an answer :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issues with your code, namely 1) In the first `while(cnt!=n)` you are not considering the case when `temp` is `null`, which leads to problems when you do:

```
 temp = temp->next
```

Moreover, you want to sum the last 'n' elements but you are actually trying to sum the elements after the first 'n' elements.

This problem is easier solved using recursion as one can see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-sum-last-n-nodes-given-linked-list/). In the iterative one approach is to count the number of elements in the list and then starting summing the elements after the `total elements - 'n'`th element is found.

```
  if(n<=0){
      return 0;
  }
  // Let us calculate how many elements are on the list.
  Node *temp = head; 
  int total_elements = 0;
  while(temp != null)
  {
     total_elements++;
     temp = temp -> next;
  }
  int n_th = total_elements - n;
  if(n_th < 0) return 0;
  
  temp = head;
  int cnt = 0;

  // Here we do need to check temp for null 
  // because we know temp has at least n_th elements
  while(cnt != n_th)
  {
      cnt++;
      temp = temp->next;
  }
  temp = temp->next ;
  int sum = 0;
  while(temp != NULL)
  {
      sum += temp->data ; 
      temp = temp->next ;
  }

  return sum ;
```

A different approach is to during the counting of the number of elements in the list we also sum all the elements, then in the end we subtract the (initial) elements that should not be part of the sum:

```
  if(n<=0){
      return 0;
  }
  // Let us calculate how many elements are on the list.
  Node *temp = head; 
  int total_elements = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  while(temp != null)
  {
     total_elements++;
     sum += temp->data;
     temp = temp -> next;
  }
  int n_th = total_elements - n;
  if(n_th < 0) return 0;
  
  temp = head;
  int cnt = 0;

  while(cnt != n_th)
  {
      cnt++;
      sum -= temp->data;
      temp = temp->next;
  }

  return sum ;
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of where the segmentation error might happen is when n is equal to the length of the linked list.

In your example, if we set `n` to be 7, `temp` pointer will be forwarded 7 times inside the while loop. So, it reaches the end of the linked list. Now if you do `temp = temp->next ;` at the end of the linked list you would then have a segmentation error as there is no next element in the linked list.

A simple/naive solution to this problem would be:

1. Count the total number of elements in the list.
2. Subtract it from `n` to get the number of elements that you have to ignore initially.
3. Sum up the rest of the elements.

There could be other/better ways to solve this, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem would be with this loop

```cpp
while(cnt!=n)
  {
    temp = temp->next ;cnt+=1 ; 
  }
```

You are incrementing `temp` for `n` times. But you are not even checking whether `temp` is pointing to a valid entry or not. Is it `NULL` or not.

Secondly the logic is wrong. You are skipping first `n` number and calculating sum of remaining numbers. What you should do is to get the total number and then iterate this above mentioned while loop till `total_num - n` times. After that do the sum of sum of remaining numbers.